# Long layover at Incheon international Airport

Tags: visas, layovers, south-korea, icn

I have a question related to my trip to Korea.

I am Cambodian, I will have a trip from Cambodia to Jeju and of course I can get in Jeju without visa.

But from Jeju to Cambodia, I will have a long layover at Incheon international Airport, 23h, I do want to go to downtown Seoul. Can I go out the airport without a visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not leave South Korea when flying from Jeju to Incheon Airport, so your entry stamp from arrival should still be valid.

With a 23 hour layover in your itinerary, one would assume that your flight from Jeju to Seoul is only a domestic flight, even if they do allow you to check your bags through to Cambodia.  If by chance they offer you the option to clear immigration in Jeju, simply tell them you want to do immigration in Seoul.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Cambodians are eligible for a special 30 Days Visa-Free Access to Jeju Island, but normally need a visa for South Korea (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Cambodian_citizens). I'm not sure if they can also visit Seoul during a layover. Perhaps you could add a link to an official source.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland - It is my understanding that the Jeju Visa Free entry allows stays up to five days on mainland Korea when your primary destination is Jeju with a tour group.  Similar to China's transit visa, in that you can only visit in the region surrounding the airport you are connecting through for Jeju. I can not find a link that addresses the issue exactly as the OP described, but they can double check with their tour provider.

Comment: @Tom Oh, OK. I don't know too much about it, but I was worried for the guy.

Answer (score 1):

[Republic of Korea Visa portal](http://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=1010201#visa_list05)<sup>1</sup>'s B-2 visa requirement says... <sup>2</sup>

> Visa Free Entry for foreign transfer passengers
>
> ## Eligibility
>
> Besides the passengers for transit mentioned above, those transferring through the Incheon Airport and taking part in the Transit Tourism Program on their way to a third country or the country of their nationality (hereinafter referred to as "general transfer passengers")
>
> ## Condition of Permission
>
> General Transfer Passengers: Possessing a transfer ticket and staying in the Seoul Capital Area for up to 72 hours

Seoul Capital Area is usually Seoul, Incheon, Gyeonggi.

So you can legally stay in Korea for 72 hours. Note that It is (by definition) different from B-2-2 (Tourist / Transit (Jeju)) visa. Since Jeju Island is an autonomous province where they have more lax visa requirement, visa policy is bit different. Of course, best way to confirm is to check with [Korea embassy in Cambodia](http://khm.mofa.go.kr/).

---

1: Click "English" at the top, then "Short Term Visit", "Tourist / Transit (Jeju)". Link defaults to Korean website when I try to visit, but maybe because my IP is Korea.

2: I said visa, but you're still visa-free.